# Design of contrast for GLM in voxel-wise analysis

Tags: generalized-linear-model, contrasts, neuroimaging

I'm attempting voxel-wise analysis of biomedical imaging (DWI-MRI) using FSLs GLM GUI (https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/GLM) but got confused when designing more complex experimental designs. The GLM allows for analysis of designs where "the response Y at each voxel is modeled as a linear combination of one or more predictors, stored in the columns of a "design matrix"".

My design matrix/data frame looks like the following:

| Favorable Outcome | Poor Outcome | TICI | NIHSS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 3 | 12 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 7 |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | 8 |

Each row is one patient, divided into two groups (Favorable vs. Poor Outcome) and having two additional information, the TICI score (ordinal, 0-4) and the NIHSS score (continuous, 0-42).

I now want to design a contrast that shows voxels that are associated with lower TICI in the Poor Outcome group when compared to Favorable Outcome group, while correcting for the covariate NIHSS.

Using the linked manual for creating GLM contrasts, I came up with the following contrast:

| Favorable Outcome | Poor Outcome | TICI | NIHSS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 1 | -1 | 0 |

I'd be very grateful if someone could either confirm or dismiss that this contrast would show the aforementioned voxels or something entirely different. Please tell me if I can provide additional information to make the matter more clear. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you have created "bad outcome" and "good outcome" as separate variables when they are completely dependent, i.e. bad = 1 - good. You only need one of these. For simplicity, take "good". There is no need to estimate the contrast, you can directly test the hypothesis regarding the sign of TICSS coefficient.

Comment: Thanks, I already suspected that this division of variables might not have been a good idea. 
If merge them again into one variable ("GoodOutcome"), could the correct term for testing the hypothesis be something similar to `GoodOutcome(-1), TICI (-1), NIHSS (0)`?

Comment: If you insist to go the contrast route, you have to confirm what the model is, A contrast is a function of the covariates, not the response, which you're showing. The contrast will be ok only if you don't include the interaction of TICI and NIHSS in predicting outcome.

Comment: Problem is, given the way the GUI is structured (https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/GLM#Single-Group_Average_with_Additional_Covariate for reference), I don't understand how to implement hypothesis testing with multiple variables without a contrast? Sorry for lacking understanding of this.